# Unable to send email with Outlook

Tags: outlook-2010

Using Outlook Version 14.0.6123 on several notebooks (same make and model) with Windows 7. Some users can send and receive email, Others can only receive email.

Their Outlook settings are identical (except for username and password). They are all connected to the same internet provider. Some send, some don't.

Trying changing the outgoing port from 25 to 587 doesn't help. However, when I connect to my phone Hot Spot I can send fine. And when users are connected to the internet from a hotel it works fine. Just not in the office where some work and some don't.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have a networking problem in the office.  You don't give much in the way of details on who the mail provider is or if it resides in house so can't be too sure.

Either way I would take a look at a router or switch that may be having issues routing all of the traffic or maintaining connection for the clients.  You may also want to provide more details about the setup in order to get additional help.